# How to arrange data frame elements using group column order stored in another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames with equal number of rows. The snippet is

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id = c(123, 124, 125), X1 = c(1, 2, 1), X2 = c(NA_integer_, 1, 2))
df1
    Id X1  X2
1  123  1  NA
2  124  2   1
3  125  1   2
df2 <- data.frame(Id = c(123, 124, 125), X1_1 = c(NA_integer_, 2, 1), X1_2 = c(1, NA_integer_, 2), X1_3 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_1 = c(NA_integer_, 1, NA_integer_), X2_2 = c(NA_integer_, 3, NA_integer_), X2_3 = c(NA_integer_, 2, 2))
df2
  Id X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3
1 123  NA    1    2   NA   NA   NA
2 124   2   NA    3    1    3    2
3 125   1    2    3   NA   NA    2
```

I need to create list with arranged df2 elements accordingly group positions from df1 and remove NA:

```
$`123`
[1] 1 2

$`124`
[1] 1 3 2 2 3

$`125`
[1] 1 2 3 2
```

How to create this list in R?

**UPD**
Example of real data is [here](https://gist.github.com/drastega/5916d5dd4df01f0f009980698e709eb1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `lapply`, `sappy`, `sort` and `grep`:

```
lapply(setNames(df1$Id, df1$Id), function(i) {
  x <- df2[df2$Id==i, unlist(lapply(paste0("^", names(sort(df1[df1$Id==i,-1])), "_"), grep, colnames(df2)))]
  x[!is.na(x)]
})
#$`123`
#[1] 1 2
#
#$`124`
#[1] 1 3 2 2 3
#
#$`125`
#[1] 1 2 3 2
```

Comment: When I try to apply your code to real data I get Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list'. The code works only when I unlist(sapply(...)) but with incorrect result. This is because of wrong sorting in case of length(colnames(df1)) > 10.

Comment: I understand that but my df1 is completely numeric. I try to figure out why it acts like character

Comment: I guess the problem is in partially similar results for grep('X1', ...) and grep('X10', ...), for example

Comment: @drastega Oh yes, Thanks! I added a `paste` which should fix the bug.

Comment: Thank you @GKi! You did it in the most elegant way

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option

```
Map(function(u, v) {
     nm1 <- sub("_\\d+", "", names(v))
     grp <- match(nm1, unique(nm1))
     as.vector(na.omit(unlist(split.default(v, grp)[unlist(u)], use.names = FALSE)))

}, split(df1[-1], df1$Id), 
 split(df2[-1], df2$Id))    
#$`123`
#[1] 1 2

#$`124`
#[1] 1 3 2 2 3

#$`125`
#[1] 1 2 3 2
```

Comment: I appreciate your help VERY MUCH @akrun! You even do not realize how much I learn from your answers

Comment: How to fix your code for data with length(colnames(df1)) > 10? Unfortunately the code does not work when df1 has X10 and more columns.

Comment: @drastega  Not clear about the issue.  Could you be more specific

Comment: The code works only if df1 has less then 10 columns (max X9). In other case it return's wrong (too short) vectors in the list

Comment: @drastega  Can you update with an example.  I get a feeling of what is happening

Comment: @drastega Is it the `UPD Example`

Comment: @drastega  If I check the "Id" in both datasets, it is different

Comment: @drastega  Did you intend to have "123" as the same Id for both datasets?

Comment: I've fixed it. Yes both Id should be the same.

Comment: @drastega  Thanks, I fixed it.  It is because we were `split`ing by the column names and the order got changed after `X9` because the sorting is different.  for e.g. `sort(c("X1", "X25", "X10", "X2"))`